# A js event for js Chrome extension (work on every tab had loaded a page)

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I need a js event that must be activated immediately an page loaded and run a function just in that tab.
In Chrome browser platform.

Comment: Depends on what specifically that function will be doing. You probably need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). By default it runs after DOMContentLoaded event in tabs with the matching URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Define your extension in a JSON called **manifest.json**. Here you need to specify which tabs will execute your app, for example tabs that match https://css-tricks.com/*

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Your Extension Name",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://css-tricks.com/*"],
      "js": ["index.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

2) Write your app. Here after loading all resources you can add your function. I'm using **console.time** to check how long it takes.

**index.js**

```
console.time('time')

window.addEventListener('load', event => {
    console.log('All resources finished loading!')
    console.timeEnd('time')
})
```

Hope this help :)